# Reference subquery column in outer main SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

For an online course script

This is the SQL I have written:

```
  SELECT l.`id` as parent_lesson_id, l.bigImageURL, l.name, 
(SELECT `percent` as percent FROM courses.`lesson_sessions` 
WHERE lesson_id = parent_lesson_id AND user_id = 52461 ORDER BY `percent` DESC LIMIT 1) as percent  
FROM courses.lessons l  
WHERE l.courseID = 1 AND percent > 30 
ORDER by `order` ASC
```

I am using a subquery because I am returning a single row (which has the highest percentage), and not all of them. If I used `LEFT JOIN`, I don't know how I would only return rows which have the highest percentage for that parent_lesson_id

A lesson can have many lesson_sessions which each have a percentage

I am getting the following error message when running this query:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'percent' in 'where clause'
```

Problem I am trying to solve:

> How to return all lesson rows, where percentage > 30, taking only the highest percentage row related to the lesson from lesson session table (a lesson can have many sessions, each with a different lesson completion percentage).
>
> Basically I want to return all the lessons where the highest percentage is >30

Comment: Remove the `s from percent in the where clause

Comment: I still get the same error @t1f

Comment: Edit your question and provide snapshots of all relevant tables structures as they currently stand (name - columns etc)

Comment: Better are text CREATe tables and to repproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a derived column in the `WHERE` clause and this is not allowed:

```
WHERE .... AND percent > 30
```

`percent` is a derived column.

MySql allows the use of derived columns in a `HAVING` clause, so change to this:

```
SELECT 
  l.id as parent_lesson_id, l.bigImageURL, l.name, 
  (
    SELECT percent FROM courses.lesson_sessions 
    WHERE lesson_id = l.id AND user_id = 52461 
    ORDER BY percent DESC LIMIT 1
  ) percent 
FROM courses.lessons l
WHERE l.courseID = 1 
HAVING percent > 30
ORDER by l.`order` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the maximum percent somewhere else than inside your subquery, then move the subquery from the `SELECT` clause to the `FROM` clause. In order to do so, get the maximum by lesson with aggregation.

```
SELECT 
  l.id as parent_lesson_id, 
  l.bigImageURL, 
  l.name, 
  p.max_percent as percent  
FROM courses.lessons l  
JOIN
(
  SELECT lesson_id, max(percent) as max_percent
  FROM courses.lesson_sessions 
  WHERE user_id = 52461 
  GROUP BY lesson_id
  HAVING max(percent) > 30
) p ON p.lesson_id = l.id;
WHERE l.courseID = 1
ORDER by order ASC;
```